# Rustboot errors with Rust 1.8.0 nightly compiler

Tags: rust

I am attempting to fix Rustboot, so that it will build and run in the Rust 1.8.0 nightly using i686-unknown-linux-gnu. I have two main errors that I cannot seem to fix, and these are it:

```
main.rs:50:5: 54:6 error: the trait `core::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for the type `IntRange` [E0277]
main.rs:50     for i in range(0, 80 * 25) {
main.rs:51         unsafe {
main.rs:52             *((0xb8000 + i * 2) as *mut u16) = (background as u16) << 12;
```

and

```
main.rs:52:15: 52:44 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
main.rs:52             *((0xb8000 + i * 2) as *mut u16) = (background as u16) << 12;
```

Any ideas on why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Link to Rustboot main.rs file: http://pastebin.com/wyDywYN8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IntRange` does not implement `core::iter::Iterator`, so naturally it can't be used in a `for` loop. The error about the type of `i` is related - since `IntRange` does not implement `Iterator`, so when it is used as one, the type of its items is not known.

You should implement `Iterator` instead of providing `next()` as an inherent method:

```
use core::iter::Iterator;

impl Iterator for IntRange {
    type Item = i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

This may be not enough, however, because `for` loop also relies on `Option`, but I don't remember now whether it is a lang item or if it is looked for by a full path.